# Does any built in ARRAY function in VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c++-cli

For example, I have a 10 elements array called 'R'.
I have use 3 of that elements. Can VC++ tell me that which elements are empty and the corresponding index numbers? I googled, but I could not find an answer. (maybe I don't have a good keywords). Please help thanks

Comment: @Marco I think what you want is `std::map` like container.

Comment: What type of elements does the array contain?

Comment: The array contains another class objects.

Comment: @Mahesh I am sorry that I am a super new user. I do not understand what you mean. Would you please explain it further?

Comment: @Marco On what basis are you filling certain elements of an array ?

Comment: A standard, simple, built-in array is fairly primitive.  It doesn't have any facility for telling you which elements have been assigned values and which you haven't.  You have to keep track yourself.  There are other containers that have additional functionality.  But you specified an array, and arrays are not meta-introspective objects.

Answer (score 0):

you simply could reserve a special value that marks an element as unused. initialize your your array elements with that value and reset the element to that value when it's not used any longer. the way vc++ "tells" you that the elements are unused would then be via the debugger that shows you the reserved value for the unused elements or make a little wrapper class for the array with a function returning the index so there would be not as much oberhead as you have using a template class or stuff like that